Reading large CSV files and saving to parquet
I want to analyze a 125Gb CSV file. I have c500Gb of RAM available to me. When I try doing read_csv, I get a ComputeError. Instead, I tried scan_csv and sink_parquet (to reduce file size) and I got the following error message:

polars.exceptions.ComputeError could not parse ~.

Not sure what I can do here?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path\Python\Scripts\Process.py", line 55, in process_daily_status
    ).sink_parquet(path = parquet_file)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Path\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\polars_utils\unstable.py", line 59, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Path\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\polars\lazyframe\frame.py", line 2116, in sink_parquet
    return lf.sink_parquet(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: could not parse `

I tried read_csv() and scan_csv().
Code being used:
try:
    if not os.path.exists(parquet_file) or force_update:
        pl.scan_csv(source=csv_file, schema=DataTypes.daily_status_dtypes).sink_parquet(
            path=parquet_file
        )
except Exception as e:
    print("+" * 120)
    traceback.print_exception(e)
    return False


Is that the full error message?

Yup. The code I'm using is:
try:
if not os.path.exists(parquet_file) or force_update:
pl.scan_csv(
source = csv_file,
schema = DataTypes.daily_status_dtypes
).sink_parquet(path = parquet_file)
except Exception as e:
print("+"*120)
traceback.print_exception(e)
return False

Can you try running just this code: print(pl.scan_csv(csv_file).head().collect())? (This will try to read just the first 10 rows of the file and print it.)

Do you get the same CompyteError when using read_csv?
